# Extract value in a row, obtained from the count of entries, based of a name

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Basically, I have a sheet with a list of names in column A, and a value in the next one (B). Names are repeated constantly in A. I want to be able to extract a specific number for each of the names listed. The number I'm looking for each of the names should be the one located under the 90th percentile of the total amount of entries under that name. Basically, not the first nor last number found, but the one located in a specific row, taking into account that we should only be counting the rows that show the name of a specific person, and not anyone else.

I'm trying to use INDEX with VLOOKUP, obtaining the row with ROUND, however, this formula returns the row number based off of the entire array, and not off of the count of the specific names.

Looks Like this... https://ibb.co/kSm9Y5S. The idea is for example, for  all values from Edgar, to return the one under the row (0.9*(1+number of entries that Edgar shows). So, if Edgar has 10 entries, I want to return the value located under row number 0.9*(10+1), without counting the rows in which Edgar isn't an entry. In this case, I only want Edgar's entries to be counted, and to return the value that Edgar shows under his 90th percentile.

My formula looks like this:

=index(A:B,Round(0.9*(1+vlookup(countif(A:A,"Edgar"),A:D,4,0))),2)

This formula is working, but is returning the value in a specific row of the sheet, and not a specific row based of the entries that Edgar has only.

Comment: Please make a copy of your Sheets file, remove all sensitive info, Share it to "Anyone with the link", and add that link here.

Comment: Here, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s1EseOVpsCkwc4qKLxLU00AOngHQ9g6bXXp9OlFozi4/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

I wish all questions displayed such prior effort—you're already basically there. Cheers!

I made another new tab, Report, and put my example formulas there. First it just lists all the names ("Owners") it can find.

```
=UNIQUE(Sheet1!A2:A)
```

Then, (if A isn't blank), it does your math, but INDEXes into a [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)-result array rather than directly into the list of *all* Owner values.

```
=IF(NOT(LEN(A2)),"",INDEX(
  FILTER(Sheet1!C$2:C,Sheet1!A$2:A=A2),
  ROUND(0.9*(1+COUNTIF(Sheet1!A$2:A,A2)),1)
))
```

I couldn't put it in an ARRAYFORMULA because of the COUNTIF, but drag-copying it down the column works fine.